# Backbone parse server response to model

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, backbone.js

I'm trying to deal with a server response, and am a little confused how to turn the json response into Backbone Models.

My Backbone model looks like so:

```
 Entities.Recipe = Backbone.Model.extend({
      defaults: {
           id: '',
         name: '',
 introduction: ''
               },
     parse: function (response)
        {
          if(._isObject(response.results)){
            return response.results
          else {
            return response 
          }
        })

 Entities.RecipeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
       url: 'recipes',
     model: Entities.Recipe
   )}

var API = {
   getRecipeEntities: function (){
     var recipes = new Entities.RecipeCollection()
     var defer = $.Deferred()
      recipes.fetch({
          url: 'http://3rdpartyApilocation.com/recipes'
      success: function (data) {
         defer.resolve(data)
      }
   })

   var promise = defer.promise()
   $.when(promise).done(function (fetchedData)
     {})
   return promise
   }


RecipeManager.reqres.setHandler('recipe:entities', function()
{
   return API.getRecipeEntities()
}
```

And the response.results is an Array of objects - with each object having an id key, a name key and an introduction key.  But because I am so inexperienced with Backbone I have no idea how to map those results to the model?   [image]

I have installed Chromes Marionette inspector and when I look at the entire array of results seems to be passed to the model, rather than each individual object within each response.result being set to each individual model.  Sorry if I can't be more clear - I'm very new to Backbone... [image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your confusion is because you're in fact able to use `parse` on a model or on a collection. And from your explanation it looks like the `response.results` object returns a list of objects that you want to become models in your application. But because you're catching that object in a model, the model doesn't know what to do with that array.

Let's say you have a response like this:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Pie"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Rice"
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Meatballs"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then you would just use `parse` on your Collection to let it know the response isn't array itself, and help it find it in the `results` property.

Here's a working example:

```js
var Recipe = Backbone.Model.extend();

var Recipes = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Recipe,
  url: 'http://www.mocky.io/v2/56390090120000fa08a61a57',
  parse: function(response){
    return response.results;
  }
});

var recipes = new Recipes();

recipes.fetch().done(function(){
  recipes.each(function(recipe){
    /** Just demo of the fetched data  */
    $(document.body).append('<p>'+ recipe.get('name') +'</p>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js'></script>
<script src='http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js'></script>
```